# Create bigInteger from buffer in javascript

Tags: reactjs, cryptography, biginteger

I am using a bigInt library in gatsby, like this

```
import BigInteger from 'bigi';

const signature = ecdsa.sign(shaMsg, BigInteger.fromBuffer(privateKey));
```

There seem to be some polyfill issues on the production build that I haven't been able to fix. When running in localhost there are no issues.

So I figured I would try a different bigInt library to see if this fixes it

```
import bigInt from "big-integer";
```

The thing is this library does not have a `fromBuffer` function, and `signature` in the code above is type buffer.

How can I convert it, other than using the function from the 'bigi' library?

Thank you (does this question even make sense, because I don't know what I am doing)

Edit: For clarification, console logging `BigInteger.fromBuffer(privateKey)` in the development build (the one that works) results:

```
BigInteger {0: 5218218, 1: 6291014, 2: 34656281, 3: 1776116, 4: 53518743, 5: 10808093, 6: 62725491, 7: 63913863, 8: 50275223, 9: 1979384, t: 10, s: 0}
```

In the production env, where it does not work, the same log for the above

```
n {0: 5218218, 1: 6291014, 2: 34656281, 3: 1776116, 4: 53518743, 5: 10808093, 6: 62725491, 7: 63913863, 8: 50275223, 9: 1979384, t: 10, s: 0}
```

I don't understand what happens, maybe the problem is in the `ecdsa` library as suggested by a commentator below

The error I get in production is

```
Expected property "1" of type BigInteger, got n
```

Edit: I solved this, I was helped somewhere else, by using elliptic instead of ecdsa to make signature, as suggested below, it was an ecsda issue. I can't close because of the bounty, nor post an answer, so I don't know what to do

Comment: Your question makes sense to me. Maybe you can create a bigint of a byte, left shift 8, create a bigint of the next byte and add it, left shit 8 and so on. Shift is generally not a very expensive operation (but since JS doesn't really do integer types, I don't exactly know how fast it is).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes how do I create a bigint of a byte and how  left shift 8? How is that done?

Comment: You can just index bytes in the buffer using brackets I think, then you can use the biginteger constructor with a single argument. `shiftLeft` is a method of the big integer class, right?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it's the first time doing this thing, so IDK. Do you think this library may help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with the implementation of BigInteger and more with your `ecdsa.sign` function. What library is this?

Comment: @ArtjomB. it's "ecdsa": "^0.7.0"

Comment: A Java BigInteger will accept a byte array.  Can you convert your buffer to a byte array?

Comment: OK, I've looked into ecdsa. They are using bigi in their test suite, so this should be compatible.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I added in the questions the console logs for BigInteger.fromBuffer(privateKey) in both environments

Comment: @rossum If I do ecdsa.sign(shaMsg, Uint8Array.from(privateKey)), then error message says "Expected property "1" of type BigInteger, got Uint8Array" or something like that. Is it some other type of byte array to convert to

Comment: I already solved this, someone helped me somewhere else, using elliptic instead of ecsda library, I am not allowed to close it, so IDK what to do

Comment: @user3808307 let the bounty lapse, the rep is lost regardless

Comment: @Mordechai rally ? :O

Comment: perhaps a crypto library like this one https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl or this one https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js be of more help?

Answer (score 0):

The [ecdsa](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/ecdsa) library is deprecated ([source](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/ecdsa/issues/27#issuecomment-638666724))

> Use [secp256k1](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node) or [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic) if you need other curves.